How to prevent object inheritance
On my App.vue file I have this object being provided:
let myObject = ref(null)
provide('myObject', myObject)

In a component file I have this object being injected like this:
const myObject = inject('myObject')

below I have this variable:
let myVariable = null
When I make myVariable equal to value of myObject and then change a key value on myVariable, the same key value changes in myObject and when I run this:
console.log(myObject.value)
console.log(myVariable)

myVariable = myObject.value

console.log(myObject.value)
console.log(myVariable)

myVariable.symbol = 'new value'

console.log(myObject.value)
console.log(myVariable)

I see that myObject and myVariable appear to inherit the same changes.
How can I make it so that myVariable becomes a copy of myObject without being linked to myObject so I can manipulate it independently?

the dumbest way would be to serialize (JSON.stringify) it to json and deserialize it back (JSON.parse) to make a "deep copy" of myObject.

also "inheritance" is not the correct term, given both myObject and myVariable "points" to the same instance. a good read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language

Your issue with these objects doesn't seem to have anything to do with inheritance, rather the "copy" refers to the same object.

Use structuredClone to make a copy

Generally it's a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/how-do-i-correctly-clone-a-javascript-object . Any solution that's applicable to JS in general is applicable in Vue except structuredClone, it won't work in 3. The question doesn't contain enough info for an answer that suit it better
